# What does 'a' stand for in 'a-C' according to research paper lingo?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, carbon-family

I came across [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925963516302254) but I cannot figure out what is **a-C** as it is not defined. The **C** here is obviously **Carbon**. Regarding '**a**' prefix My best guess is that it stands for amorphous. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

a for amorphous is totally correct. Also used in other publications like [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00018738600101911).